# Elementary OS dual boot with windows 7

Tags: boot

previously my laptop was having two partition, C and D.  On C:\ i had windows 7 install.  I wanted to make a dual boot system with Elementary OS Freya.  Hence i made a separate 6 GB EXT3 partition from my D:\ and install Elementary OS on the Seperate partition

The installation was successful.  I restarted the laptop and found both Windows 7 and Elementary OS options.  However when i selected Windows 7 it did not boot.  However elementary OS was working fine.  I want both the os to work

While installing EOS, i was not connected to internet, nor i try to ran the update through the internet after the EOS installation was sucessfull.

Comment: Most likely the Elementary OS overwrote the Master Boot Record (MBR) on your laptop having GRUB 2 handling the boot menu. And it configured the GRUB menu entry for Windows 7 incorrectly. You have to options at this point: load from Windows Live CD and repair Windows 7 MBR (then you'll probably have to use EasyBCD to tell your Windows 7 boot loader about Elementary OS), or fix grub configuration leaving GRUB 2 as a default boot loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above solution does not work.  i have finally formatted all the partitions, install elementary OS a fresh.  Now i am planning to install windows 7 as second OS.  Finding the tool to create a bootable USB so that i can create windows 7 bootable from Elementary OS

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to leave the GRUB 2 as a default boot loader, then you can try the 2nd option of the boot repair procedure as described in [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, so the procedure should probably work for the Elementary OS too.

If this approach won't work you can try posting contents of your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file so people can help you debugging the problem.

You can also try restoring Windows 7 boot loader from Linux. Here is a couple of guides for restoring Windows MBR from Linux - [one](http://robert.penz.name/221/mini-howto-restore-windows-mbrbootloader-with-linux/) and [two](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/repair-windows-mbr-from-ubuntu/).

You can also grab a Windows 7 installation CD and repair your Windows 7 MBR with it. Here is a guide for [restoring Windows MBR with Win Install CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).